# PHP Using File_get_Contents() to pre populate a form

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a site to help learn some PHP MVC. At the moment the site carries out the CURD commands but I am looking to improve on them.

The items of the database are displayed in on column with two buttons, one to delete and one to update. When the user clicks the update button a form (`update_item_form.php`) is displayed that will allow the user enter the item information to be update. The form consists of three fields (title, price and description)

What I am trying to do: When the user clicks the update button the form will be pre populated with all the item information connected with that row.

How will can I send the row information to the form when the user clicks the button?

**file_get_contents()**

```
$rightBox = file_get_contents( "templates/update_item_form.php" [database value] );
```

**Update_item_form.php**

```
<h2>Update Item!</h2>
<h4>Fill in the form to update an entry.</h4>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <input id='action' type='hidden' name='action' value='updateItem' />
    <p>
        <label for="fTitle">Title</label> <input type="text"
            id="fTitle" name="fTitle" placeholder="title"
            maxlength="25" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="fPrice">Price</label> <input type="text"
            id="fPrice" name="fPrice" placeholder="price"
            maxlength="25" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="fDescription">Description</label> <input type="text"
            id="fDescription" name="fDescription" placeholder="description"
            maxlength="500" required />
    </p>

    <p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: CURD? Little Miss Muffet would be truly excited. You would have to be able to parse the returned contents to get the bit you need to set the form values. If the contents are markup you will likely want something like DOMDocument to perform the parsing with.

Comment: I provided an answer about output buffering but your question is sort of all over the place so I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: Okay, the question I would have to ask is what is the purpose of update_item_form.php being a PHP file if you don't have any PHP code and are using file_get_contents?  Your code (controller) should pass variables to the template (view) and the template should display them.

Comment: That was just a mistake in transcribing over

Comment: @patrick Since you appear to not have figured this out yet, I thought my comment above would help since you stated you were using an MVC design.  The view, in this case I assume `template/update_item_form.php`, should display variables passed to it by the controller.  You have no PHP in your template file, so you aren't going to be displaying any variables to the end user with that design.

Answer (score 2):

file_get_contents won't parse a PHP file.  All you're doing is loading the *code* into `$rightBox`, not the *output* that I assume you are after.

For that, you can use output buffering.

```
ob_start();
include "templates/update_item_form.php";
$rightBox = ob_get_clean();
```

This will store output between `ob_start()` and the `ob_get_clean()` into `$rightBox`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am having some trouble understanding this however, would you be able to explain how I could use this to pre populate the form?

Comment: Well, what is update_item_form.php?  Slim down your question and make it more clear and then maybe I can offer some more advice.

Comment: Updated the question to make it a little more clearer